# PL/SQL "SQL Command not properly ended" error

Tags: sql, plsql, scripting

I am currently working on developing some SQL scripts in PL/SQL Developer and I am getting an:

> SQL Command not properly ended

error that I am unsure how to solve.

The code I am using looks something like this

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table as
    SELECT * FROM table_x

INSERT INTO temp_table
    SELECT * FROM table_y
```

If I execute the two pieces (`create table` and the `insert`) as separate pieces everything runs fine, i.e. select each code block and execute. However if I try to execute everything, select all code and execute, I get an error saying that:

> SQL Command not properly ended

I don't mind dealing with this when I am dealing with very small tables but when I have a significant number of operations I need to execute sequentially and when each operation takes a long time to run I would like to be to execute the code and walk away.

Adding a semicolon raises a new error which is an error:

> invalid character

This is the code that raises the invalid character error.

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table as 
    SELECT * FROM table_x where x > 1; 

INSERT INTO temp_table 
    ( 
    SELECT * FROM table_y where x > 1; 
    )
```

Comment: Adding a semicolon raises a new error which is an "invalid character" error. 

This is the code that raises the invalid character error. 

    CREATE TABLE temp_table as
        SELECT * FROM table_x where x > 1;

    INSERT INTO temp_table 
        (
        SELECT * FROM table_y where x > 1;
        )

Comment: Put the final semicolon at the END of the Insert statement, not in the inner Select statement

Answer (score 7):

Put a semicolon at the end of each statement.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table as
SELECT * FROM table_x;

INSERT INTO temp_table
SELECT * FROM table_y;
```

I think the parentheses were messing you up.

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis can be used to specify the columns on which you want to insert the data as in:

INSERT INTO temp_table     ( col1,col2,...coln) SELECT ...

You get an error because instead of a list of columns, the parser finds a select expression between parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the script in one step in PL/SQL Developer, you may need to convert it to a "SQL*Plus" script - i.e. the semicolons are required to delimit the statement, then the / (forward slash) is required to run the statement, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table as 
    SELECT * FROM table_x where x > 1;
/

INSERT INTO temp_table 
    SELECT * FROM table_y where x > 1;
/
```